# How to pivot with occurrences row

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a kind of pivot table of data and here is a contrived example.

```
  Animal       Date  Occurence
0    dog 2017-01-10          2
1    cat 2017-03-06          3
2    dog 2015-02-03          1
3    cat 2016-04-05          2
```

Final df

```
  Animal  Count  Year
0    dog      1  2015
1    cat      0  2015
2    dog      0  2016
3    cat      2  2016
4    dog      2  2017
5    cat      3  2017
```

I have looked at the pivot method of the dataframe but it doesn't allow me to multiply the count by the occurrences column.

The only code I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({
        'Date': [datetime(2017,1,10), datetime(2017,3,6), 
                 datetime(2015,2,3), datetime(2016,4,5)],
        'Occurence': [2,3,1,2], 
        'Animal': ['dog','cat','dog','cat']})
```

Is there a pandas way of doing it?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Thanks for attempting to ask a quality question. Just for the future, please only keep the question to the question. You "complaining" about your lack of permissions doesn't profit anyone, especially not you getting a proper answer to the question. Nothing for you to worry though as an edit is already queued. Have a nice day! (From Review https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/17614773 )

Comment: I have previously avoided Stack Overflow "like the plague" because of these very political issues.  Its usually just not a good fit for my needs.  Unfortunately Pandas "forgot" to provide alternative means of providing support which I feel was a bit remiss on their part.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) + [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df1 = (df.set_index([df['Date'].rename('Year').dt.year,'Animal'])['Occurence']
        .unstack(fill_value=0)
        .stack()
        .reset_index(name='count'))
print (df1)

   Year Animal  count
0  2015    cat      0
1  2015    dog      1
2  2016    cat      2
3  2016    dog      0
4  2017    cat      3
5  2017    dog      2
```

Or use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html):

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([pd.unique(df['Animal']),
                                  pd.unique(df['Date'].dt.year)], names=('Animal','Year'))

df1 = (df.set_index(['Animal', df['Date'].dt.year])['Occurence']
         .reindex(mux, fill_value=0)
         .reset_index(name='count'))
print (df1)
  Animal  Year  count
0    dog  2017      2
1    dog  2015      1
2    dog  2016      0
3    cat  2017      3
4    cat  2015      0
5    cat  2016      2
```

EDIT:

If pairs in columns `Year` with `Animal` are duplicates, solutions above failed:

```
df1 = (df.set_index([df['Date'].rename('Year').dt.year,'Animal'])['Occurence']
        .unstack(fill_value=0)
        .stack()
        .reset_index(name='count'))
print (df1)
```

> ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

So you need unique pairs - need aggregation. Fastest is `groupby` with aggregate function like `sum`:

```
print (df.groupby(['Date', 'Animal'])['Occurence'].sum())
Date        Animal
2015-02-03  dog       1
2016-04-05  cat       5
2017-01-10  dog       2
2017-03-06  cat       3
Name: Occurence, dtype: int64
```

You can also extract years from datetimes and aggregate:

```
df2 = df.groupby([df['Date'].rename('Year').dt.year, 'Animal'])['Occurence'].sum()
print (df2)
Year  Animal
2015  dog       1
2016  cat       5
2017  cat       3
      dog       2
Name: Occurence, dtype: int64
```

Then for filling zeros for all combinations `Year`s with `Animal`s use solutions above:

```
df3 = df2.unstack(fill_value=0).stack().reset_index(name='count')
print (df3)
   Year Animal  count
0  2015    cat      0
1  2015    dog      1
2  2016    cat      5
3  2016    dog      0
4  2017    cat      3
5  2017    dog      2

mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([pd.unique(df['Date'].dt.year),
                                  pd.unique(df['Animal'])], names=('Year','Animal'))

df4 = df2.reindex(mux, fill_value=0).reset_index(name='count')
print (df4)
   Year Animal  count
0  2017    dog      2
1  2017    cat      3
2  2015    dog      1
3  2015    cat      0
4  2016    dog      0
5  2016    cat      5
```

Comment: `pd.unique(df['Animal'])` is same as `df['Animal'].unique()`

Comment: Something does not look right here.  Shouldn't there be a "sum()" in there somewhere to account for the "occurrence" row specifying more than one instance in a single row?  Can you break it down for me why this works?